# Centralizar componentes de uma dataTable que esteja em edição dos dados no Primefaces

Tags: html, css, css3, jsf, primefaces

Como posso centralizar os componentes desta `datatable`. Quando clico para editar os dados da mesma percebo que os componentes de entrada de dados não ficam centralizados, mas ao utilizar um certos testes com css consegui chegar para o lado mas não ficam precisamente ao centro de cada coluna.

[image: Imagem da datatable]

Seria possível tal fato?

Comment: Cada elemento do primefaces tem uma ou mais classes de estilo, procura qual é a classe dos componentes que quer centralizar e centralize-os usando essa classe.

Comment: @Patrick eu cheguei a utilizar o `direction` e `margin-left` e consegui movimentar utilizando o inspector do `Google Chrome` consegui trabalhar. Mas não fica centralizado.

Comment: Você já tentou usar `margin: 0, auto`?

Comment: @Patrick aplicando sobre a tag `ui-cell-editor-input` não deslocou, lembrando que é uma `div`

Answer (score 1):

Para aqueles que desejam, incluam na sua folha de estilo a seguinte propriedade.

```
.ui-cell-editor-input {
    text-align: center;
}
```

E quando se editar os dados da `datatable` o componente de `edit` ficara ao centro.